# mysql create table DATA DIRECTORY

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to change the data directory of a MySQL table using the following command. I am trying in windows. But it is not working. Can somebody tell me the reason?

```sql
CREATE TABLE clients
(
  client_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, 
  client_name VARCHAR(75), 
  telephone CHAR(15)
)
DATA DIRECTORY = 'e:\data\mysql';
```

The table is created. But it is created in the default data directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> These options work only when you are not using the --skip-symbolic-links option. Your operating system must also have a working, thread-safe realpath() call. [See Section 7.9.6.2, “Using Symbolic Links for Tables on Unix”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/symbolic-links-to-tables.html), for more complete information.

Windows does not have a working, thread-safe `realpath()` call, so you can't do this.

Comment: Current MySQL (5.6.x): You can use DATA DIRECTORY with Windows. Requirement: Storage Engine is InnoDB and option `--innodb_file_per_table` is enabled.